# Nginx ingress controller without load balancer in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

Can we use nginx ingress controller without loadbalancer? If so what are the measures that needs to be taken to setup the ingress controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use nginx ingress controller without loadbalancer?

Yes, of course

> If so what are the measures that needs to be taken to setup the ingress controller?

To set it up? `helm` install it (or whatever mechanism you want), and ensure its `Service` is `type: NodePort`. Then, `curl -H 'host: my-virtual-host.example.org' http://${node_ip_address}:${http_node_port}`

Comment: You can find a good tutorial for this [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) that goes step by step and will use Helm as well.

Comment: Hey buddy, what will be my endpoint IP address when there is no external IP provided by Load Balancer?

Comment: the end point will be the external IP for any of your nodes along with the nodeport so something like 35.35.35.35:32000, but this is not a single end point and any of your nodes could fail causing the IP to disappear. For a single endpoint IP it is recommended to use the network load balancer